# AddObject and Save Not Working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a DBML where I have my table within a MVC environment.

```
db.TruckTable.AddObject(trucktbl);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It isn't working as it can't find `AddObject()` pertaining to the `TruckTable`. I am wordering if there is another way around this to make a table save that is in a DBML file.

Comment: how you are obtaing trucktbl object

Comment: Assuming this is Entity Framework - which version?

Comment: If it is a DBML file, then it is linq-to-sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With linq-to-sql the method to add objects is called `InsertOnSubmit()` and saving changes is done through `SubmitChanges()`.

```
db.TruckTable.InsertOnSubmit(trucktbl);
db.SubmitChanges();
```