# LINQ 2 SQL: AddObject and InsertOnSubmit

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I need to insert a record into Payment table. I found two methods to do it

1. AddObject
2. InsertOnSubmit

What is the difference between the two? When to use what?

```
    public void InsertEntity(DBML_Project.Payment payment)
    {
        //Insert the entity
        MyDataContext.GetTable<DBML_Project.Payment>().InsertOnSubmit(payment);
    }


public void InsertPayment(IPayment payment)
{
     this.AddObject(payment.GetType().Name, payment);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some related questions:

- [AddObject and Save Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621902/addobject-and-save-not-working)
- [Can't find InsertOnSubmit() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333811/cant-find-insertonsubmit-method)

They do *roughly* the same thing, but [AddObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx) belongs to Microsoft's [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) and [InsertOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516) belongs to Microsoft's [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

For either of them, you will want to commit the changes to the database when you're done adding objects. Call [SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savechanges) after AddObject and call [SubmitChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) after InsertOnSubmit.

Since you mentioned that you're using LINQ to SQL, you probably want InsertOnSubmit.